# How to set a lamp as camera?

Tags: modifiers, objects, light

I'm trying to set my lamp as camera, but every time I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>0</kbd> it says: Modifier cannot be added to the object area.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> (or <kbd>1</kbd>,<kbd>2</kbd>,<kbd>3</kbd>, and so) is to add a Subdivision Modifier, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> is to use an object as camera